# jquery time picker addon for date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, timepicker

I'm trying to implement the jQuery UI Date Picker with the Time Picker addon (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

I have the js and css saved in the same directory as my script as timpicker.js and picker.css respectively.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="picker.css" />
<script src="timepicker.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$('#from').datetimepicker();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
</body>
</html>
```

Firebug keeps giving me these errors:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

})(jQuery);

datetimepicker.js (line 1919)

TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$('#from').datetimepicker();
```

Has anyone else come across this problem.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I have been unable to find anyone with the same problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are loading the timepicker.js before you load jQuery.  Your page is trying to run timepicker.js and doesn't know anything about jQuery.  Rearrange your scripts like:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="timepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Took care of the errors.  Thank you.  Unfortunately when I click the text box i get no action. Any ideas?

Comment: That is a similar error.  You need to wrap the initialization of the timepicker in a $(document).ready() or move the script tag to the end of the file.  Remember that javascript is executed at the point it is located in the html.  So as your page is, the input doesn't exist when the js is executed.